# Does the linkedin API support webhooks

Tags: linkedin-api

Does linkedin API support webhooks or any other mechanism to deliver notifications to the API consumer? We have a client that require an app to monitor they several accounts and they require some way to get notifications of events like when some profile get liked or viewed

Comment: did you find any solution ?  #linkedin

Comment: No at the time, and we moved away integrating linkedin into our system

Answer (score 3):

There is presently no webhook support for any LinkedIn APIs.

Comment: And how tools like Zapier get notifications from Linkedin? do they query the API using pooling?